# Can I use self leveler over existing floor

Tags: flooring

First the floor is a mess. Is a closed in back porch that had glued down linoleum on it. Is un even. Most of linoleum was scraped up and then a garage floor paint was applied on top of that. Now the paint is peeling and chipping in spots because of moisture coming up from concrete that was never sealed because it was a back porch originally. Can I use a self leveling concrete over this mess and start fresh or do I have to have all of this grinded out?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What is supporting the floor? Would the weight of the (perhaps thin) concrete be a concern?

Comment: If the concrete floor is good general shape then it will depend on which self leveling coating you plan on using.  That will determine how far you need to go on surface prep.

Comment: The floor is concrete has a problem with sweating because was never sealed or had moisture barrier. Other flooring had been put on but mold is an issue

Answer (score -1):

Use Plani patch 1mix 2 liquid looks like milk try to get loose paint off first

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We like longer, more detailed answers, with punctuation. If this is important to you, please edit your question to improve it.